# How to add a CSS class or id to Html.PagedListPager

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have this PagedListPager :

```
@Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)Model, page => Url.Action("InboxWithNoReplyListPaging", new { page = page }), PagedListRenderOptions.EnableUnobtrusiveAjaxReplacing(new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "GET", UpdateTargetId = "inboxWithNoReplyList"}))
```

I am trying to add some kind of interaction when navigating between pages, since when you navigate from page 1 to whatever, the page just changes without any interaction to the end-user. I already have a CSS class which loads a spinner, but I am not sure how to add it into the PagedListPager as there is no option for that. I tried using this :

```
$('.pagination-container').click(function () {
     $("#progress").show();
    setTimeout(function () { $("#progress").hide();},5500)
    });
```

But obviously, this isn't reliable at all.

If you have any further question or want to know any more code let me know. Any kind of help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

lol I read the documentation to realize there's LoadingElementId right there in AjaxOptions.. I will keep this post up in case someone faces the same problem.. if ever

Comment: please use comments instead of posting it as an answer